# Своя кнопка в диалог фрагмент

Tags: java, android, dialogfragment

У меня к классу наследуемому от DialogFragment  подключен интерфейс DialogInterface.OnClickListener.

Как я понимаю, этот интерфейс требует реализовать вот эти методы. Два последних для чего нужны я понял.

```
  @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

    }
    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface unused) {
        super.onDismiss(unused);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface unused) {
        super.onCancel(unused);
    }
```

Судя по документации первый нужен для определения какая кнопка нажата и что выполнить. Если это так , то как мне воспользоваться им, чтобы я мог указать какой код должен выполниться при нажатии на кнопку , которая есть в разметке, которая подключена к этому диалог фрагменту. Первым делом я найду эту кнопку

```
 Button vk_share = (Button)form.findViewById(R.id.vk_button);
```

А что дальше?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В документации сказано:

> the button that was clicked (ex. BUTTON_POSITIVE) or the position of the item clicked

Раз ты наследуешься, это какое-то кастомное диалоговое окно? Вряд ли в этот интерфейс поступит ID от кастомной кнопки. Просто найди кнопку и задай ей нужный слушатель
**UPD**
Да, я понял тебя, но ты подключил кастомную кнопку через разметку, правда не знаю, можно ли так выражаться :D
Суть в том, что в обычном диалоговом окне есть три кнопки - positive, negative и neutral. Ну, что-то вроде ОК - ОТМЕНА... Их можно указать:

```
public class FireMissilesDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_fire_missiles)
           .setPositiveButton(R.string.fire, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   // FIRE ZE MISSILES!
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   // User cancelled the dialog
               }
           });
    // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
    return builder.create();
}
```

А заместо того, чтобы указывать слушатели сразу для таких кнопок, можно реализовать интерфейс, который ты написал. И тогда в метод onClick в переменную which поступит одна из трех констант - BUTTON_NEGATIVE, BUTTON_NEUTRAL или BUTTON_POSITIVE. Дальше уже я думаю понятно.
Ссылки по теме - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.html#BUTTON_POSITIVE

Comment: нет. окно не кастомное. диалог фрагмент ведь может отображать то что я задам в xml , т.е. окно я создаю такое , какое я хочу. И я туда добавил кнопку, не кастомную. Вот мне и хочется слушатель на неё поставить. Кнопку то я найду.  Я думаю что можно подключить интерфейс View.OnClickListener , но мне всё же интересно для чего нужен первый метод в приведенном мной коде

Comment: ну я так и думал, что это связано с тремя этими кастомными кнопками. Хотел подтверждения . А сам я уже реализовал другой интерфейс View.OnClickListener, и в нём по Id нахожу кнопку и всё работает. Только кое что меня не радует : я в этом методе не могу написать вот так  dialog.dismiss(); Т.е. чтобы мой диалог после того как я нажму на кнопку сперва выполнил мой код и затем закрылся. Надо как то организовать подачу диалога в этот метод. Вот в DialogInterface.OnClickListener поступает диалог.

Comment: Хмм, я думаю должно быть что-то вроде getDialog(). Но это не точно, в крайнем случае - можно сохранить ссылку на dialog при вызове onCreate

Comment: getDialog().dismiss();  да он есть) Работает как надо. спасибо